# How to make a function that makes an array?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a function that generates an array of numbers within a certain range.
A very basic question but I couldn't find an explanation...
I tried this

```js
var newArray = [];
function makeArrey(start, last) {
 var length = last - start;
 for(var i = 0; i <= length; i++) {
  newArray[i] = start + i;
 }
 return newArray;
}
makeArrey(1, 100);
alert(newArray[4]); //4 is a random number to see if it works, it dont work
```

Comment: And what doesn't work? What's the question?

Comment: What you expect from code?

Comment: Are you trying to make a function that generates an array of numbers within a certain range?

Comment: "Nothing happens?" That's unlikely. In any case, if you want to *return* an array, then don't also mutate a global variable. Create a new array. In any case, you're creating the array and filling it--it works "fine".

Comment: If you run your own code (click on the "Run code snippet" button) you'll see that it'll (seemingly) work.

Comment: This code works absolutely fine. It should better create its own array and you should not call the function for the side effect but to get the new array as the return value, but the code is correct and working.

Comment: If by "not work" you mean that it's not alerting 4 as you would expect, that's because arrays start at index 0 which would mean index 4 holds the 5th element.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working perfectly fine. You're just forgetting that arrays start at index 0. So when you do something like `newArray[4]` it returns the 5th element of the array, which is `5` in your case.

For the sake of fixing your code so that it behaves nicer, do this:

```
function makeArray(start, last) {
    var range = [];
    var length = last - start;
    for(var i = 0; i <= length; i++) {
        range[i] = start + i;
    }
    return range;
}

var newArray = makeArray(1, 100);
```